# Default implementation for hashCode() and equals() for record vs class in Java

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, java-record, java-17

Tried with sample code to check default behaviour of `equals()` and `hashCode()` for **record** vs **class**, but it seems behave differently for **record** compare to **class**.

Here is code sample for **record** and **class**

```
public class EqualsAndHashcode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var employeeA = new Employee(101);
        var employeeB = new Employee(101);
        var employeeAClass = new EmployeeClass(102);
        var employeeBClass = new EmployeeClass(102);
        var printStream = System.out;
        printStream.println("record equals: " + employeeA.equals(employeeB) + "\nhashcode objA: " + employeeA.hashCode() + "\nhashcode objB: " + employeeB.hashCode());
        printStream.println("\nclass equals: " + employeeAClass.equals(employeeBClass) + "\nhashcode objA: " + employeeAClass.hashCode() + "\nhashcode objB: " + employeeBClass.hashCode());
    }
}

record Employee(int empId) {
}

class EmployeeClass {
    int empId;

    EmployeeClass(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
}
```

After execution output for above code is:

```
record equals: true
hashcode objA: 101
hashcode objB: 101

class equals: false
hashcode objA: 935044096
hashcode objB: 396180261
```

Can anyone please help me to understand how record's default implementation for `equals` and `hashCode` behaves differently as above?

And if there is a change in the `equals` and `hashCode` implementation for record, then please help me to understand what exactly the purpose of that change and in which scenarios it will be more helpful to use.

Comment: The entire purpose of a record is to be a _value object_, so automatic comparisons make sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In a nutshell the difference is simple:

- the default implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `java.lang.Object` will never consider two objects as `equal` unless they are the same object (i.e. it's "object identity", i.e. `x == y`).
- the default implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` for records will consider all components (or fields) and compare them for equality (or consider them for the hash code). If they all match then `.equals()` will return `true` and `hashCode` will return the same values.

The details documented for [`java.lang.Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) are:

> As far as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object returns distinct integers for distinct objects.

In practice this means that any object which doesn't override `hashCode` anywhere in its type hierarchy will return what is called the "identity hash code" which is effectively an arbitrary but constant number.

As for [`java.lang.Record.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#hashCode()), it says:

> The implicitly provided implementation returns a hash code value derived by combining appropriate hashes from each component. The precise algorithm used in the implicitly provided implementation is unspecified and is subject to change within the above limits. The resulting integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application, even if the hashes of the component values were to remain consistent in this way. Also, a component of primitive type may contribute its bits to the hash code differently than the hashCode of its primitive wrapper class.

And for `equals()` methods;

[`java.lang.Object.equals(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) :

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, **this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object** (x == y has the value true). In other words, under the reference equality equivalence relation, each equivalence class only has a single element.

[`java.lang.Record.equals(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) :

> **The implicitly provided implementation returns true if and only if the argument is an instance of the same record class as this record, and each component of this record is equal to the corresponding component of the argument**; otherwise, false is returned. Equality of a component c is determined as follows:
> If the component is of a reference type, the component is considered equal if and only if Objects.equals(this.c, r.c would return true.
> If the component is of a primitive type, using the corresponding primitive wrapper class PW (the corresponding wrapper class for int is java.lang.Integer, and so on), the component is considered equal if and only if PW.compare(this.c, r.c) would return 0.
> Apart from the semantics described above, the precise algorithm used in the implicitly provided implementation is unspecified and is subject to change. The implementation may or may not use calls to the particular methods listed, and may or may not perform comparisons in the order of component declaration.

For more discussion, see [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).