# Are Java Records suitable to represent the nodes of a graph?

Tags: java, java-14

One of the classic ways to represent a graph (as in Graph Theory) is:

```java
class Node {
  String value;
  List<Node> children;

  // constructor, equals, etc. are omitted
}
```

The question is with respect to using the new [Records feature introduced in Java 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html)

Specifically, are there any potential pitfalls with using a declaration like below for an algorithm like DFS:

```java
record Node(String value, List<Node> children) {}
```

One potential problem is with respect to the `equals` / `hashCode` method provided by records. I imagine that, in the case of `Node`, the implementations provided by record could result in infinite recursion (StackOverflow).

For example, consider the code below that uses a `Set` collection.

```java
import java.util.*;

class SO {
    
  static void dfs(Node n, Set<Node> visited) {
    if (n == null) return;
    System.out.println("visited " + n.value());
    for (Node child : n.children()) {
      if (visited.contains(child)) continue;
      visited.add(child);
      dfs(child, visited);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var a = new Node("a", new ArrayList<>());
    var b = new Node("b", new ArrayList<>());
    a.children().add(b);
    b.children().add(a);
    dfs(a, new HashSet<>());
  }

}

record Node(String value, List<Node> children) {}
```

This code results in a StackOverflow:

```
% java SO.java
visited a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Node.hashCode(SO.java:25)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:595)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:582)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.hashCode(Objects.java:103)
    at Node.hashCode(SO.java:25)
    ... <omitted> ...
```

Does this mean the use of record is generally unsuitable for graph algorithms ? If not, how to correctly implement such algorithms when used with record ?

Comment: Why wouldn't records be suitable?

Comment: @Bohemian Have edited the question to improve clarity. Please consider re-opening.

Comment: The short answer is No, they are not explicitly unsuitable.   To make your example work, you need to override the default implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` provided by the base class for records ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332957.  In your use-case you need "identity" based equality, not "value" based equality for the nodes.  (Value based equality won't work on a recursive record type ... like your `Node` type.  You will get infinite recursion in `equals` and `hashCode`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace reveals the cause of the stack overflow error.

The problem is the circular relationship you've created - a is a child of b and b is a child of a - causes an infinite loop when calculating the hash code of the node.

A `record` calculates its hash code using all fields. In turn, a `List` calculates its hash code using the hash code of all of its elements. Because a's list includes b, and b's list includes a, the calculation of hash code, which happens for every object passed to a HashSet method, descends infinitely.

The fix is to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` to not involve `children`, probably using Object implementation via `return super.hashCode();` etc

Or don't define circular relationships.

Comment: This would break the contract of `Record.equals`.