# java record with mutable properties (like set or list) with equals()

Tags: java, equals, java-record

I know, Java `records` are **value based**, i.e. by default two records are equal if both records have the same values (compared to Java `classes` where by default two classes are equal if their memory addresses are the same).

Am I right with the following assumption that this:

```
public record User(String name, Set<String> hobbies){}
```

is the same as this:

```
public record User(String name, Set<String> hobbies) {
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, hobbies);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {

            // check for "memory equality" (also in java records???)
            if (this == obj) return true; 
            if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

            // check for "value equality"
            final User other = (User) obj;
            return Objects.equals(name, other.name) 
                    && Objects.equals(hobbies, other.hobbies) ;
        }
    }
```

My question is:

Is **my** `Equals/HashCode` implementation exactly the same as the **automatic/generated** `Equals/HashCode` implementation? If I do not provide an `Equals/HashCode`, then Java records adds a default one, but will it also include the check for **"memory equality"** or only does it only check for **"value equality"**?

Comment: The behavior of the default implementation of the `hashCode/equals` methods of records is specified by their [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: What do you even mean by “*to put hobbies into the equals/hashCode methods*”? What is your question about?

Comment: **My question is:** Is my `Equals/HashCode` implementation exactly the same as the automatic/generated `Equals/HashCode` implementation? If I do not provide an `Equals/HashCode`, then Java records adds a default one, but will it also includes the check for "memory equality" or only does it only check for "value equality"?

Comment: It’s not “exactly the same” but it will use the `hashCode` and `equals` implementations of the components, if that’s what you want to know.

Comment: Look at the example code above. Will java records have the following code lines in their equals-method: `// check for "memory equality"
            if (this == obj) return true; 
            if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;`? That's the only important question.

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69333053/10343888).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implementation dependent.

If you take a look at the Javadoc of [`Record#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Apart from the semantics described above, the precise algorithm used in the implicitly provided implementation is unspecified and is subject to change

and [`Record#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#hashCode()):

> The precise algorithm used in the implicitly provided implementation is unspecified and is subject to change within the above limits.

So, implementations are free to implement it however they want as long as they only use the components (and use all components).

However, most implementations will probably add a check for reference equality (`==`) in `equals` so that the other checks don't need to be done in case the objects are the same **but you shouldn't rely on that**.

The null check and the check that the argument is of the same type are necessary to obey to the contract of `Object#equals` but the latter could also be done using an `instanceof`-check or something implemented natively.

Comment: “But you shouldn’t rely on that.” That’s the most important sentence. As I need the *reference equality* also for record, it forces me to *always* override the `equals/hashCode` of records so I can be sure it has consistent behavior regardless of JDK implementations.

Comment: It's pitty that the Java record specification doesn't enforce *consistent* behavior here..

Comment: Why should it? Leaving that open makes it easier to do optimizations in the future (e.g. if it only has a single primitive component, it could just check that component) and this could also make migration to future value classes easier.

Comment: Leaving that open can lead to inconsistent behaviour and consistent behaviour is, in my opinion, more important than optimization.

Comment: But ok, records are a "value based" entity. So it makes sense to only test for "equal values" and *not* for "equal references"..

Comment: Equal references imply equal values. Checking `==` beforehand is an optimization that doesn't make any functional difference _as long as all components fulfill the `Object.equals` contract_ (specifically reflexivity).

Comment: The “check == before” is indeed an optimization. There is no need to compare all values ​​of a record/class if the instance points to itself. That's why I'm wondering why the spec for records doesn't also specify that two records are the same even if they are the same instance (one and the same identity). You say "Leaving that open makes it easier to do optimizations in the future.." but “check == before” **is** or would be the optimization.

Comment: If two records are equal by reference comparison, all components are equal as well. Also, there might be improvements in the future where the reference comparison would be in the way (e.g. maybe they want to just compare the memory segments 
(for components) instead of the reference comparison or the JVM could attempt to inline it).